# Progress 4GL report with centered header

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

How can I create a report with a centered header? In the header I would like to put a variable too.

Comment: You need much more information to make this question answerable. Is it character based or web? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

In the plain old 4GL you can specify the left edge of a field in a frame using AT or the right edge with TO.

There is no attribute that centers a field within a frame.

You end up coding something similar to this:

```
define variable middle as character no-undo format "x(40)".

middle = "some text".

display
  "left" at 1 middle at 20 "right" to 80 skip
with frame hdrFrame1 with no-labels.

pause.

middle = fill( " ", integer( 20 - ( length( middle ) / 2 ))) + middle.

display
  "left" at 1 middle at 20 "right" to 80 skip
  with frame hdrFrame2 no-labels.
```

(assumes a width of 80 chars and a "middle" field 40 chars wide...)

If you are using a fancy report generator or creating HTML then those tools have their own solutions.